# Autoload Emacs ESS

Tags: emacs, load, autoload, ess

How to autoload ESS in Emacs (for Windows)?

It always starts up with an opened ESS buffer, and I suspect loading ESS slows down loading emacs by approximately 1 second (using timer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not posible at the moment. There are too many entry points. There has been some work done on integrating ESS with package.el, but it was left unfinished because of the limitations of package.el in Emacs 24.1 Hopefully it is solved by the next release of ESS (13.03).

Do you compile? It speeds up loading considerably. You can do that with `make` or `make lisp` in terminal. Alternatively open dired in the ESS/lisp directory marke all .el files (with <kbd>*.</kbd> el<kbd>RET</kbd>)  and do `M-x dired-do-byte-compile`.

Comment: I was thinking, what about creating a function that loads ess-site upon finding a .R file? EDIT: Maybe someone could create a minor mode that triggers on .R files, followed by loading ess-site?

        (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.R\\'" . r-mode))